# C++ segmentation fault caused by malloc operation when dealing with vector

Tags: c++

A wired segmentation fault confused me for a while, I define a struct as follow:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        pc = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        memset(pc, 0, 10 * sizeof(char));
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        free(pc);
    }
    Foo(const Foo& f)
    {
        if(this == &f) return;
        strncpy(pc, f.pc, 10);
    }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& f)
    {
        if(this == &f) return *this;
        strncpy(pc, f.pc, 10);
        return *this;
    }
    char * pc;
};
```

Then I put the instance into a vector:

```
vector<Foo> vf;
Foo f;
strcpy(f.pc, "hello");
vf.push_back(f);
```

But segmentation fault happend when run to the push_back() line, I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: In the copy-constructor you use `pc` uninitialized

Comment: `malloc` … `memset` … `strncpy` … **why**?!?

Answer (score 3):

Your copy constructor is wrong.

```
Foo(const Foo& f)
{
    // if(this == &f) return; Not needed, see comment below; thanks to Matt McNabb
    pc = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // this was missing
    strncpy(pc, f.pc, 10);
}
```

The missing line was causing pc to be unallocated thus copying would fail.

Comment: The self-check is unnecessary, it's impossible to call copy-constructor with yourself as argument anyway (unless you already caused undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor allocates memory, but your copy constructor does not.

The `push_back()` creates a copy of your object inside the vector, calling the copy constructor. That uses `strncpy()` to copy your "hello"... somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor does not allocate memory for `pc`, therefore you copy memory to an uninitialized variable. If the copy constructor is called, the default constructor *is not* called.